# Pandas: How to efficiently replace <NA> values in a range of specific rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In light of the COVID-19 pandemic, I have been working with some of the data and come across a comprehensive and updated source for cases/deaths/etc:
https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv

There are some missing data, but instead of taking out my 'dropna' sledgehammer, I wanted to see what was going on and recover anything that could be recovered. It turns out that the two-letter country code of Namibia is 'NA,' and is seen as missing when imported.

I am working in Pandas 1.0.1 so I started out converting the columns to a string:

```
dt = pd.read_csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv")    
dt['geoId'] = dt['geoId'].astype('string')
```

Now I could have just used a '.fillna()' at the end of that but I wanted to handle any future cases where there were real NaNs.

My solution seems like a bit of a hack and probabaly not optimal:

```
namibia_rows = dt['geoId'][dt['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'Namibia'].index
for x in namibia_rows:
    dt.loc[x, 'geoId'] = 'NA'
```

Is there a better way to do this using a single line and a built-in Pandas function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accessor.

```py
dt.loc[dt['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'Namibia', 'geoId'] = 'NA'
```

That allows you to specify a filter as the first parameter, and a column name as the second. With the combination of these, you can pinpoint the values you want to replace and set them all at once.

With your example data:

```py
dt = pd.read_csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv")
dt['geoId'] = dt['geoId'].astype('str')

dt[dt['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'Namibia'].head()
#          dateRep  day  month  year  cases  deaths countriesAndTerritories geoId countryterritoryCode  popData2018
# 7103  16/04/2020   16      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia   nan                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7104  15/04/2020   15      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia   nan                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7105  14/04/2020   14      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia   nan                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7106  13/04/2020   13      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia   nan                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7107  12/04/2020   12      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia   nan                  NAM    2448255.0

dt.loc[dt['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'Namibia', 'geoId'] = 'NA'
dt[dt['countriesAndTerritories'] == 'Namibia'].head()
#          dateRep  day  month  year  cases  deaths countriesAndTerritories geoId countryterritoryCode  popData2018
# 7103  16/04/2020   16      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia    NA                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7104  15/04/2020   15      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia    NA                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7105  14/04/2020   14      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia    NA                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7106  13/04/2020   13      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia    NA                  NAM    2448255.0
# 7107  12/04/2020   12      4  2020      0       0                 Namibia    NA                  NAM    2448255.0
```